# What is the correct format for this email header?

Tags: php

How can I send the $email correctly?

```
$headers .= 'From: SUB: .$email.'  . "\r\n";
```

Comment: @mithunsatheesh maybe for you. But I can not send it correctly

Answer (score 3):

Either use double quotes (don't recommend it):

```
$headers .= "From: SUB: {$email}\r\n";
```

Or do it properly and get the variable outside the quotes:

```
$headers .= 'From: SUB: '.$email."\r\n";
```

As you can see, you were very close, but the ' should be placed before the first dot and not after the email variable :-)

Comment: Why not recommend embedding the variable? Any half-way decent editor will properly highlight the variable.

Comment: Because when you get the variables outside the quotes it's less easy to make mistakes. In the case I wrote here there's no difference (actually the single quoted version may be slightly faster because it doesn't have to be parsed) but it's a good habit.

Comment: Use `sprintf()` to separate variable names from the string for more modularity and less errors.

Comment: Haha, yeah, I agree, but that feels like major overkill for such a simple thing. If you're working on i18n or things like that it may actually be a good idea though.

Answer (score 2):

$email should be in double quotes `"From: Sub: $email\r\n";` or concat properly `'From: Sub: ' . $email . "\r\n`"

Answer (score 1):

`$headers = 'From: Sub:'. $email . "\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

You should make it quoted-printable:

```
$headers .= sprintf("From: \"SUB:\" <%s>\r\n", $email);
```

Will create a header-line like the following:

```
From: "SUB:" <mail@example.com>
```